# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 18: What is the $\epsilon$ $\delta$ proof for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} e^{-1/x^2}=0$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, logarithms, exponential-function

At the very end of Ch. 18 of Spivak's *Calculus*, he investigates the function

$$f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}, x\neq 0$$

Consider the behavior of this function near $0$.

> If $x$ is small, then $1/x^2$ is large, so $e^{1/x^2}$ is large, and
> $e^{-1/x^2}=\frac{1}{e^{1/x^2}}$ is small. **This argument, suitably**
> **stated with $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s, shows that**
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} e^{-1/x^2}=0$$

My question is what is the argument suitably stated with $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s?

**Here is my attempt**

Let $\delta>0$.

$$|x|<\delta =\implies -\delta<x<\delta \implies 0<x^2<\delta^2\implies 0<\frac{1}{\delta^2}<\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Since the exponential function is increasing and always positive we have

$$1<e^{1/\delta^2}<e^{1/x^2}$$

and

$$0<e^{-1/\delta^2}<e^{-1/x^2}<1$$

For any $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon<1$, choose $\delta$ such that

$$\epsilon=e^{-1/\delta^2}$$

This means $e^{1/\delta^2}=\epsilon^{-1}\implies\frac{1}{\delta^2}=-\log{\epsilon}\implies \delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\log{\epsilon}}}$ (important to note again that $0<\epsilon<1$).

Then $0<e^{-1/x^2}<\epsilon$.

Now consider an $\epsilon\geq 1$. In this case choose $\delta$ as

$$\delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\log{\alpha}}}$$

for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then

$$0<e^{-1/x^2}<\alpha<1\leq \epsilon$$

Hence we have shown that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x, |x|<\delta \implies |e^{-1/x^2}|<\epsilon$$

thus

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} e^{-1/x^2}=0$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You might try using Spivak’s result that, provided one limit exists, for $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, we have $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(1/x)$.

Comment: You wrote it wrongly when changing the inequality, just above "For any epsilon...".

Comment: @MehmetKırdar What exactly is wrong there?

Comment: You have to start with $\forall \epsilon>0$ instead of $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<ε<1$ and $x\in (-δ,δ)$, where $δ$ is a positive number. Then $|e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}}|=e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}}<e^{-\frac{1}{δ^2}}$, because exponential is increasing and $x\in (-δ,δ)\implies |x|<δ\implies x^2<δ^2\implies \frac {1}{δ^2}<\frac {1}{x^2}\implies-\frac {1}{x^2}<-\frac {1}{δ^2}$. Choose $δ:=(-lnε)^{-1/2}$ (which is obviously well defined and positive) and acquire $|x|<δ\implies -\frac {1}{x^2}<-\frac {1}{δ^2}
\implies e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}}<e^{-\frac{1}{δ^2}}=ε.$